# Not a locally compact space that can be represented as union of two locally compact spaces (open and close) [R. Engelking, exercise 3.3.C]

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Define a subspace of the real line that can be represented as the union of two locally compact subspaces, one of which is closed and the other open, and that is not a locally compact space.

Comment: Note that although this looks like a PSQ, posik has immediately posted an answer. (Self-answer mode).

Comment: @311411 From https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer "Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."

Answer (score 2):

Let $$A=(0, 1]\setminus\left\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}, \quad B=\{0\}.$$
the set $A$ is open and locally compact because it can be represented as union of open sets
$$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
and for every point $x\in A$: $x\in \left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$ and
$\left[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right]$ is compact.

The set $B$ is closed because it can be represented as complement of open set:
$$\{0\}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\left((-\infty, 0)\cup(0, +\infty)\right).$$
And $B$ is locally compact.

We are going to show that $X=A\cup B$ is not locally compact space.
Let us take any neighborhood $U$ of point $0$ in the topology of $X$.

Let us take a fundamental sequence $x_n$ in $U$
such that $x_n\to \frac{1}{k}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
We can take such sequence because any neighborhood of $0$ has
infinitely many points of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Notice that $x_n$ hasn't limits in $U$.
And also it has no convergent subsequence in $U$ because otherwise, the limit should be equal to $\frac{1}{k}$
which does not belong to $U$.

Using this we can conclude that $U$ is not compact.
So, we have shown that every neighborhood of point $0$ is not compact in $X$.
That means that $X$ is not locally compact.

Comment: +1. Any open or closed subspace of $\Bbb R$ is locally compact...... BTW we could also say that$U\supset [0,r)\cap X$ for some $r>0$, so $U\supset J_n=(1/(n+1),1/n)$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and $J_n$ is a closed, non-compact subset of the Hausdorff space $U$, so $U$ cannot be compact.